# h(k) = k mod m, where k is a character string interpreted in radix 2^p and m = 2^p – 1. Show that h(x) = h(y)

Tags: algorithm, hash, radix

The full question is:

Consider the hash function:

> `h(k) = k mod m`, where k is a character string interpreted in radix 2<sup>p</sup> and m = 2<sup>p</sup> – 1. Show that by permuting characters in string `y` we can derive string `x ⇒ x` and `y` hash to the same value.

I have decided that there are two ways to solve this problem.  I can either show that

`h(x) - h(y) = 0` or

> h(x) = (x * (2<sup>p</sup> - 1)) % (2<sup>p</sup> - 1) which would always equal 0 no matter what x we use

I've looked up several solutions online but I'm very confused with this problem.  I think my biggest problem is I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the radix information to solve this problem.

Can I get a hint as to how I should begin this problem?

Comment: Do you know the old trick to quickly determine whether a number is divisible by 9? It's the same principle.

Comment: So that's the idea with the line "interpreted in radix 2^p"?  I need to add up the values of each char and show that the total is the same no matter the order.  I'll work on it!

Comment: You are essentially asked to prove a generalised version of the divisible by 9 trick.

Answer (score 1):

if `m = 2^p - 1` and k is a character string interpreted in `radix 2^p`,
Then two strings that are identical except for a transposed character hash to the same value For example let `m = 2^3 - 1 = 7` and using ASCII values for characters: 
String ``abcd'' is represented as

> k = 97 . 8^3 + 98 . 8^2 + 99 . 8 + 100 = 56828
>  which hashes 56828
>   mod 7 = 2.

String ``badc'' is represented as

> k = 98 . 8^3 + 97 . 8^2 + 100 . 8 + 99 = 57283
>  which hashes 57283
>   mod 7 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Though its too late now to answer this question but I would still go ahead and record it for two reasons: 1. help anyone looking for an answer and 2. for my own reference.

Note following mathematical facts on modulo arithmetic

1. `if a ≡ b (mod n)`
   then `a^k ≡ b^k (mod n)` for any non-negative integer k (compatibility with exponentiation)
   refer "**Properties**" section at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic
2. `2^p = 1 (mod 2^p - 1)`. For example 8 = 1 (mod 7)

---

Now, coming to proving the point asked in the question:

Let the string be `"xyz"`, when represented in radix 2^p then xyz can be written as:

```
{x.(2^p)^2 + y.(2^p)^1 + z} (mod 2^p-1)
```

= `x.(2^p)^2 mod (2^p-1) + y.(2^p)^1 mod (2^p-1) + z mod (2^p-1)`

= `x.{(2^p)^2 mod (2^p-1)} + y.{(2^p)^1 mod (2^p-1)} + z mod (2^p-1)`

from (1) and (2) above: `{(2^p)^2 mod (2^p-1)} = 1` and  `{(2^p)^1 mod (2^p-1)} = 1`
therefore, the expression is reduced to `(x + y + z)` if `(x + y + z) is less than 2^p-1` or it becomes `(x + y + z) (mod 2^p-1)`

Now, if we permute the characters of the string `"xyz"`, and solve for modulo (2^p - 1) and follow the above reasoning, we would still get either `(x + y + z) if (x + y + z) is less than 2^p-1 or get {(x + y + z) (mod 2^p-1)}`

Hope above explanation helps in clearing the doubt.

***P.S***. `x^y` means x raised to the power of y